# Best choice of options/settings framework for plugin/theme development

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, custom-field, metabox, options

My question is what is the best options/settings framework out there now to safely build custom plugin/theme upon? I found the similar question here, but it was asked 7 years ago and definitely, things changed from that time.

I used ACF a lot to manage custom meta fields and creating theme options page. The plugin is great, but the main drawbacks for me are: difficult to translate (clone/repeater field bugs with WPML, manual field translation settings for EVERY field), hard to figure out compatibility issues if included with plugin (what if ACF is already used in theme, what if it's free version or older PRO version then included etc.)

I also used [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/) and https://www.wp-hasty.com/ for settings page options that leverage native WP Settings API and are the best, in my opinion, to not overcomplicate things, but it's often that I need more advanced fields (map, repeater etc.)

I investigated [Meta Box](https://metabox.io/), [CMB2](https://cmb2.io/), [Redux](https://reduxframework.com/), [Options Tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) and [Titan Framework](http://www.titanframework.net/) and can't decide what is the best to use to include in the plugin/theme. I liked the Redux design fields and also the fact that Titan Framework is called as a class instance (less compatibility issues with other plugins?). The online Meta Box generator is also a cool thing.

So the question is, what is the best framework you like to use/tried?

Thank you and happy coding :)

Comment: What would be your answer now?

Comment: Honestly, you seem like you know your way around WordPress & have experience, so really, at this point, the 'best option' would be to code the settings yourself so they work exactly the way you want them to in every possible instance.  I've used a lot of frameworks, starters, boilerplates, etc. & I learned a lot from them, but I got to a point where I did almost as much coding undoing assumptions as I did just writing code to do what I wanted.  
If we're genuinely asking 'what's the best way', so it works exactly the way you want it to then I say 'none of them', just code it all up yourself.

Comment: Also, this is a tough question because it's very subjective - I'm sure people will disagree with whatever answer you end up accepting.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, yes, that's true. I came to the same conclusions myself. If I have time I definitely choose to code the settings myself, otherwise I fallback to ACF. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @ManojKumar, I ended up using the ACF if I need to set up something in a limited time. The local JSON feature works really great with git and allows you to push/pull settings between environments. Although it can be really hard and buggy when working on multilingual websites.

Comment: I completely forgot about the WPML part.  Every new site we start, I go and research alternatives because every site at my work is bilingual... and I’m OVER the buggy aspects of WPML and their support team.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, that's so true! I especially like the way they introduce the breaking changes (e.g. the change of options pages translation logic) without proper notice or testing. Honestly, I'm expecting something to break every time I update the WPML :/

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv If you can answer your question, I can provide the bounty to you.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using [WPSettings](https://github.com/sergeliatko/wpsettings) recently. I coded it for me to take care of admin screens and options in my projects as I did not like any of the options above.

Comment: wow looks promising. Thanks for the hint. I will definitely try this one out.